# C# - How to Run File Server without Running as Administrator?

Tags: c#, windows, administrator, fileserver

## Problem

I am trying to host a static file server using `WebApp`.

When I run the following command, it throws an error.

### Code

```cs
Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.Start<WebHostStartup>("http://192.168.0.5:123");
```

```cs
public class WebHostStartup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
    {
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "DefaultApi",
                                   routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                                   defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "ActionApi",
                                   routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                                   defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
        appBuilder.MapSignalR();
        var serviceProvider = IocStartup.BuildServiceProvider();
        config.DependencyResolver = new DefaultDependencyResolver(serviceProvider);
        appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);

        var fileServerOptions = new FileServerOptions
        {
            FileSystem              = new PhysicalFileSystem(@"C:\Temp\Test"),
            RequestPath             = new PathString("/Test"),
            EnableDirectoryBrowsing = true
        };

        appBuilder.UseFileServer(fileServerOptions);
    }
}
```

### Exceptions

```
Exception: TargetInvocationException - Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
Inner Exception: HttpListenerException - Access is denied
```

## What I have Tried

I can make it work by running the program as *administrator*.

However, this is not acceptable, as some users of this program do not have administrator access on their computers.

## Question

How can I allow this to run without the need to *run as admin*?

Is there a Windows Setting or Firewall Rule that needs to be set?

Comment: I totally approve that opening a system to the outside via http needs admin privileges.

Comment: This https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/configuring-http-and-https might help. But i assume (hope) you need admin privileges for setting up a namespace reservation.